# Pixel/Vertex Shader on top of desktop output

Tags: video, graphics, shader

I Came across this software: http://www.fly.elise-ng.net/immersivedisplaydesktop 
Which probably loads a Pixel/Vertex Shader on the graphics card output and can deform any app running on the machine.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The basic concept is known as a compositing window manager, in which windows are drawn into offscreen buffers and then the window manager composites them using GPU techniques.

In Windows Vista, 7 and 8 this is handled by a component known as the Desktop Window Manager (DWM), when you enable "desktop compositing" (which enables the Aero effects) you can access a copy of each window's back-buffer with the proper API. The API you would need to use on Windows to access the back-buffer is DWM, and the particular subset of features you would use are related to thumbnail previews. I would suggest reading up on [this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

The biggest obstacle will be that the thumbnail API only allows you to draw the thumbnail into a sub-rectangle of your window, and does not give you a native texture handle. There is probably a private undocumented API you can access to accomplish this, as I have seen commercial products that offer exactly this. I could not tell you where to begin to look for that information, however.

Comment: Thanks, did some digging on this DWM, in some places it's mentioned that it supports Shader model 2.0 but could not find a way to load them